# Twitter/G+ share buttons using wrong URL

Tags: twitter, google-plus, social-networking

I've got an odd issue that I cannot figure out. When using Twitter and Google+ share buttons, it shares the correct page title, but also gives a completely wrong URL.

What's even more weird is that it is using a URL from another website of mine, completely unrelated!

These are the buttons:

```
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="Peasquared">Tweet</a></li>
<li><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline"></div></li>
```

Here is the javascript that powers them:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I've made sure to be logged into the right account when grabbing the code for the buttons.

I don't get it!

ps. It is being done within my own Wordpress Template if that helps, but I've done this before with  no problems.

Comment: Please don't use pastebins or other external sites to hold parts of your question. I've edited it inline for you.

Comment: Is this a new rule? In the past, I was told specifically to do so.

Comment: As far as I know, it has always been the case that the content of a question or answer should be able to stand alone, so that it does not become useless if the linked content goes away. If one e.g. posts a live demo at JSFiddle or somesuch, that's fine as long as it's a *copy*, not the only place the code lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a rel=canonical link on your page pointing to a different URL. Perhaps another plugin is outputting it?

Comment: Yep, that did it! I just missed it initially. Now I have to look into if removing the canonical is worth it just for a twitter button. Thanks!